# Socket.io issue with express static path join

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to configure socket.io into a node application but i have an express static path:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

On the client side the socket.io request looks like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://MyIP:6969/lanmode');
```

On header i have the script link declared propertly extracted of CDN.

That generates an error 404, the directory of /socket.io is not found couse his location is at */node_modules/socket.io/* and my 'public' path is: /public/ so i can't acces to socket folder.

My server.js file looks like this:

```
// server.js

// set up ======================================================================
// get all the tools we need
//var $ = require('jquery'),
//    XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;



var path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 6969;
var mongoose = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');

var morgan       = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var session      = require('express-session');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');


var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

// configuration ===============================================================
mongoose.connect(configDB.url); // connect to our database

require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));//Recursos necessaris tals com imatges, css, js etc

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'ilovescotchscotchyscotchscotch' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

// routes ======================================================================
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

// launch ======================================================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Visiteu la ip corresponent amb port ' + port +' per a visualitzar el projecte');
```

anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of combination of Express and socket.io, you have to make `http.Server` instance (not an Express `app` object) become a listener in order to enable socket.io intercept requests that start with `/socket.io`.

So try to replace

```
app.listen(port);
```

with:

```
http.listen(port);
```

as described in [docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

Comment: your answer works fine! but now i can't make "emit"

for example: 

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
})

and on client side:

var socket = io('http://192.168.12.181:6969/lanmode');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });

Comment: you are using `/lanmode` namespace, so you should write this on the server side: `io.of('/lanmode').on('connection', function() {...})`